# peewee: ValueError('Missing value for %s.' % column.name) on insert_many bulk insert

Tags: python, peewee

#### Updated

@coleifer pointed out my error:

`.insert_many(data)` is correct, `.insert_many([data])` is not.

#### Original

I'm not sure why `insert_many` thinks there is a value missing.  The output of `data` suggests to me that the value is there.

`data` is a list of dictionaries.  I interpret the [docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html?highlight=insert_many#bulk-inserts) such that this is a correct data format for `insert_many`.

> We can get another big boost by using insert_many(). This method accepts a list of tuples or dictionaries, and inserts multiple rows in a single query:

The code below is what I'm working with.  I have made changes to try to use `float(ticker['v'])` so it's in-line with the definition of the table.  I've also tried to populate the `weight` column with a dummy `int` so all the fields are populated, despite the `weight` column's `null` constraint.  In either case, I'm still getting the same error.  Those changes are not reflected the code below, since they didn't change the error or resolve the issue.

###### Code

```
def ticker_stream(stream):
    print(f"stream:\n{stream}")
    """ upsert Ticker data from stream """
    data = []
    for ticker in stream:
        for symbol in vars.symbol_ids:
            if symbol['name'] == ticker['s']:
                symbol_id = symbol['id']
                data.append({'symbol_id': symbol_id, 'weighted_average_price': ticker['w'], 'total_traded_base_asset_volume': ticker['v'], 'total_traded_quote_asset_volume': ticker['q']})
    try:
        print(f"data:\n{data}")
        insert_query = (c_db.Tickers
                            .insert_many([data])
                            .on_conflict(
                                conflict_target = [ c_db.Tickers.symbol ],
                                preserve = [ c_db.Tickers.symbol ],
                                update = [data]
                            )
                            .execute()
                        )

    except PeeweeException as e:
        logging.exception(f"{e}")
```

###### Table

```
In [1]: from playhouse.reflection import print_model

In [2]: print_model(c_db.Tickers)
tickers
  id AUTO PK
  symbol INT FK: Symbols.id
  weighted_average_price FLOAT
  total_traded_base_asset_volume FLOAT
  total_traded_quote_asset_volume FLOAT
  weight INT

index(es)
  symbol_id

In [3]:
```

###### Output

```
stream:
[{'e': '24hrTicker', 'E': 1633019418650, 's': 'IOTXUSDT', 'p': '0.00216', 'P': '3.703', 'w': '0.06190', 'c': '0.06049', 'Q': '111', 'o': '0.05833', 'h': '0.06525', 'l': '0.05651', 'v': '1066120847', 'q': '65989958.82000', 'O': 1632933000000, 'C': 1633019418644, 'F': 11822513, 'L': 12020549, 'n': 198035}, {'e': '24hrTicker', 'E': 1633019419094, 's': 'BTCUSDT', 'p': '1361.38', 'P': '3.278', 'w': '42677.07', 'c': '42898.31', 'Q': '0.001', 'o': '41536.93', 'h': '43822.85', 'l': '40887.00', 'v': '365499.423', 'q': '15598442675.21', 'O': 1632933000000, 'C': 1633019419087, 'F': 1489633272, 'L': 1493071304, 'n': 3438004}, {'e': '24hrTicker', 'E': 1633019419046, 's': 'ETHUSDT', 'p': '116.83', 'P': '4.101', 'w': '2941.85', 'c': '2965.69', 'Q': '0.543', 'o': '2848.86', 'h': '3049.30', 'l': '2780.00', 'v': '2191345.813', 'q': '6446606858.84', 'O': 1632933000000, 'C': 1633019419039, 'F': 1103292619, 'L': 1106186143, 'n': 2893515}, {'e': '24hrTicker', 'E': 1633019418296, 's': 'BCHUSDT', 'p': '8.51', 'P': '1.754', 'w': '491.10', 'c': '493.77', 'Q': '0.074', 'o': '485.26', 'h': '506.13', 'l': '471.14', 'v': '280920.032', 'q': '137960347.52', 'O': 1632933000000, 'C': 1633019418289, 'F': 237467951, 'L': 237775138, 'n': 307187}, ... # omitted for brevity ... ]
data:
[{'symbol_id': 25930, 'weighted_average_price': '42677.07', 'total_traded_base_asset_volume': '365499.423', 'total_traded_quote_asset_volume': '15598442675.21'}, {'symbol_id': 25931, 'weighted_average_price': '2941.85', 'total_traded_base_asset_volume': '2191345.813', 'total_traded_quote_asset_volume': '6446606858.84'}]
Exception in thread parser:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/j/Documents/Development/crypto/binance/binance.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2673, in _generate_insert
    val = row[i]
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/j/Documents/Development/crypto/binance/c_subscribe.py", line 19, in print_fifo_stream_buffer_data
    parser(oldest_stream_data_from_stream_buffer)
  File "/Users/j/Documents/Development/crypto/binance/c_parse.py", line 20, in parser
    ticker_stream(stream)
  File "/Users/j/Documents/Development/crypto/binance/c_parse.py", line 167, in ticker_stream
    insert_query = (c_db.Tickers
  File "/Users/j/Documents/Development/crypto/binance/binance.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1907, in inner
    return method(self, database, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/j/Documents/Development/crypto/binance/binance.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1978, in execute
    return self._execute(database)
  File "/Users/j/Documents/Development/crypto/binance/binance.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2745, in _execute
    return super(Insert, self)._execute(database)
  File "/Users/j/Documents/Development/crypto/binance/binance.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2474, in _execute
    cursor = database.execute(self)
  File "/Users/j/Documents/Development/crypto/binance/binance.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3156, in execute
    sql, params = ctx.sql(query).query()
  File "/Users/j/Documents/Development/crypto/binance/binance.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/peewee.py", line 613, in sql
    return obj.__sql__(self)
  File "/Users/j/Documents/Development/crypto/binance/binance.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2730, in __sql__
    self._generate_insert(self._insert, ctx)
  File "/Users/j/Documents/Development/crypto/binance/binance.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2682, in _generate_insert
    raise ValueError('Missing value for %s.' % column.name)
ValueError: Missing value for total_traded_base_asset_volume.
In [1]:
```

Comment: You might make sure all dicts must have the same keys. It looks like one is missing a key/value for `total_traded_base_asset_volume`. Alternatively, you can provide a default for an absent field, e.g. total_taded_base... = FloatField(default=0)

Comment: @coleifer I've looked at it so many times.  Am I not seeing what you're seeing?  Looking at the output of the `data:` print above, both dics have the same keys, including `total_traded_base_asset_volume`.  Each of those keys in each of the two dicts are populated (`365499.423`, `2191345.813` respectively).

Comment: If data is a list, then you want `.insert_many(data)` -- not `[data]`.

Comment: Oh my.  Thanks @coleifer for spotting that and pointing it out.